# How to map ALT-return in .vimrc?

Tags: linux, vim, gvim, keymap

I'm trying to map a combination of left alt and return keys in my .vimrc, yet without success.

I've added all those mappings to my .vimrc file, with no effect:

```
map <M-esc> itest0<return><esc>
map <M-cr> itest1<return><esc>
map <M-return> itest2<return><esc>
map <M-enter> itest3<return><esc>
map <M-[> itest4<return><esc>
map ^[ itest5<return><esc>
```

Some info:

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd>:

- in my terminal i get `^[`
- in vim (and gvim) in insert mode i get `^[`
- After calling `sed -n l` i get:

> ```
> ^[
> \033$
> ```

I'm using terminator on Arch Linux. Behaviour described is identical no matter whether I use vim or gvim. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) Same applies to <kbd>Alt</kbd> and non-alphabetic keys. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim release.

Comment: gVim 8.2.2118: `<M/C-Enter>` and `<M/C-Esc>` both work for me. (Linux Mint 20)